# Issue with division double in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, math, apache-spark-sql, date-arithmetic, arithmetic-expressions

After division, I get wrong value:

```
...
.withColumn("percentage", regexp_replace(lit("10.62%"), "%", "").cast("double") / 100)
...
```

Expected value: `0.1062`

Received value: `0.10619999999999`

What's the problem with it? Are there any solutions without `round` operation?

Comment: @AbdennacerLachiheb Yes, You're right. I think this problem can be solved only by "round" operation. I had a similar problem in another situation. And round was only solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to spark, you can try that division in pretty much any programming languages, and you will get the same result

```
print(10.62 / 100) # result is always 0.10619999999999999
```

In most programming languages, mathematical operations, are based on the IEEE 754 standard.

Here's a more clear explanation of how IEEE 754 standard works:

> In the IEEE-754 standard, hardware designers are allowed any value of
> error/epsilon as long as it's less than one half of one unit in the
> last place, and the result only has to be less than one half of one
> unit in the last place for one operation.

I'm afraid that the only solution is rounding.

Another possible solution is to use BigDecimal, but you have to put a precision, but obly for the input, you don't have to care about the precision od the result:

```
df.withColumn("percentage", regexp_replace(lit("10.62%"), "%", "").cast(DecimalType(10, 2)) / 100)
```